# mod Rewrite : Hide php extension & replace variable name by slash

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, cpanel

Need help, It is basic Mod-Rewrite. But i am confused

My current URL:

```
http://example.com/category.php?fn=accounting-tax
```

Want look like this:

```
 http://example.com/category/accounting-tax
```

Only Apache Mod-Rewrite, No PHP please

**Update:**

***Is it possible without PHP?***

Thank you

Comment: DO you really mean the opposite - that you want to have the user enter the user friendly URL and than have that silently (without change in browser address bar) re-written on the server to point to the PHP file?

Comment: My current url is: **http://example.com/category.php?fn=accounting-tax** . Now i want it to make it like this ** http://example.com/category/accounting-tax**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fn=(.*)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ category/%2 [NC,L]
```

Assuming, you meant

`/category.php?fn=accounting-tax` should take you to `/category/accounting-tax`

without showing up on the address bar. If you want an external redirect use `[R=301,NC,L]` instead.

Comment: Could you describe the url you enter and what you get redirected to?

Comment: Just want to replace ".php?fn=" portion with "/"

Comment: please take a look question once again

Comment: No. Any extra `?params` should get appended automatically as `accounting-tax?params`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z0-9\-]+)/item/?$ /category.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```